# Android....Something wrong with my SMS receiver..Receiving messages twice

Tags: android, sms, receiver

I am receiving same message twice in a conversation.

Maybe, I have something wrong in my receiver.

Would please help me to find?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String TAG = "MessagingReceiver";

    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    private String mAddress;
    private String mBody;
    private long mDate;

    private Uri mUri;

    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";
    public static final Uri RECEIVED_MESSAGE_CONTENT_PROVIDER = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");
        abortBroadcast();

        mContext = context;
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }

            SmsMessage sms = messages[0];

            if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {
                mBody = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
            } else {
                StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                    bodyText.append(message.getMessageBody());
                }
                mBody = bodyText.toString();
            }

            mAddress = sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            mDate = sms.getTimestampMillis();

            addMessageToInbox(mContext, mAddress, mBody, mDate);
        }
    }

    public static Uri addMessageToInbox(Context context, String address, String body, long time) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("address", address);
        cv.put("body", body);
        cv.put("date_sent", time);

        return contentResolver.insert(RECEIVED_MESSAGE_CONTENT_PROVIDER, cv);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"     
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />          
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you checked if onReceive() is called twice? Put some log message and check if onReceive() is called twice... also, share your manifest where you define the intent-filter

Comment: Another point: print the action received in onReceive: "Log.d("TEST", intent.getAction());" This way, you can see if you receive same action twice... or if the action is different.... Check also if you register your broadcast only in manifest (intent-filter) or if you registered it twice

Comment: Great.. Let's check which action you received in onReceive() (also, share your manifest.xml - just the part where you define the intent filter)

Comment: Please, share the results :) What is printed in log after you added that debug message

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had been calling onReceive() twice. Once in the above broadcast receiver..Secondly, I am extending this broadcast receiver to another receiver. And that is the reason behind double messages